# Run a .sh file with Python 3 Idle

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspbian

I am trying run a sh file with python 3. My .sh file will work on Terminal. My operating system is Raspbian. I try that code :

```
import time
import os
import subprocess

# STEP 1
text='sudo somecode'
savefile=open('step1.sh','w')
savefile.write(text)
savefile.close()
time.sleep(2)

shellscript=subprocess.Popen(['./step1.sh'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
```

but it not works...

Comment: Try `text = 'somecode'`  first. (remove "sudo")

Comment: @MadLee Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/shcreater.py", line 12, in <module>
    shellscript=subprocess.Popen(['./step1.sh'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 676, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 1282, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg)
OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The is undoubtedly a permissions issue.  In order to be able to "directly" execute a file (a la "dot slash" - `./yourfile`), the file in question needs the "execute bit" set.  Try using `ls -l` to see the file you've just created with your script.  I'll bet the file does **not** have the execute bit:

```
$ ls -l ./step.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 furkan furkan 0 Nov 13 20:51 step.sh
```

Note the lack of `x` in that first column.  You might `chmod` to add the execute bit:

```
$ chmod +x ./step.sh
$ ls -l ./step.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 furkan furkan 0 Nov 13 20:51 step.sh
```

With the execute bit set, you could then use a "dot slash" construct.

However, I doubt you want to execute `chmod` from within your script, so instead tell your script the *actual* program you want to run `step.sh`, namely, `sh`:

```
shellscript=subprocess.Popen(['sh', './step1.sh'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Or in the simple case of your example, simply go directly to sudo:

```
shellscript=subprocess.Popen(['sudo', 'yourexecutable'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Note that if you're being robust, I might consider adding some absolute paths, or ensuring your PATH variable is set.  However the key to your problem is the misunderstanding of what 'executable' means.

Comment: Thank a lot it work now. Can I ask two question ? first one is how can I executable my step1.sh automatically another one how can I see terminal after start my python program

Comment: I encourage you to first attempt to google, and perhaps go through some trial and error on your own.  Second, those are potentially helpful questions for others, so I encourage you to write more SO questions _iff_ you can't find a satisfactory answer already available.